# How to integrate a code generator into a VS 2012/2015 solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-generation

I have a code generator which take XML as input and generates C++ and C# code.

I would like to integrate the code generation into a Visual Studio project and generate a C++ library and a C# assembly from these new sources.

What is the best way to achieve that? Especially, VS should detect that a change in the XML files result in the generated sources

Comment: I know only about [Text Template Transformation Toolkit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) (one more [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx)) which is built right into Visual Studio. But I don't how you can integrate your existing solution (or whether it's possible at all), because information you published is not enough to answer this question.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not suited to my needs. I just run a program for generating the code, I don't to rewrite it. I'm just wondering if there's an easy way to run the code generator and express the dependencies and output in the VC++ and C# projects?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do this with msbuild

In your vcxproj file, add the following lines:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- which files to process -->
  <SRC_GEN_XML_Files Include="$(ProjectDir)\..\*.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
  <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
   <!-- the output language -->
   <SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_TYPE>cpp</SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_TYPE>
   <!-- where to put the generated files -->
   <SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY>$(ProjectDir)..</SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY>
</PropertyGroup>
<!-- the shared script which generate the source -->
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)/msbuild/src_gen.props" />
```

Now the src_gen.props script (msbuild):

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="SrcGenChecks">
    <Error Text="No SRC_GEN XML sources" Condition="'@(SRC_GEN_XML_Files)' == ''"/>
    <Error Text="Incorrect SrcGen output type: '$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_TYPE)', valid values are 'cs' or 'cpp'" Condition="'$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_TYPE)' != 'cpp' and '$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_TYPE)' != 'cs'"/>
    <Error Text="Incorrect SrcGen output directory: '$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)'" Condition="!Exists('$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)')"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="SrcGenGenerateSources"
          Inputs="@(SRC_GEN_XML_Files)"
          Outputs="@(SRC_GEN_XML_Files->'$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)\%(Filename).$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_TYPE)')"
          BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild"
          DependsOnTargets="SrcGenChecks"
          >
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Generating '$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)\%(SRC_GEN_XML_Files.Filename).$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_TYPE)' from SrcGen XML file '%(SRC_GEN_XML_Files.FullPath)'"/>
    <Exec Command='$(SRC_GEN_EXE) -input="%(SRC_GEN_XML_Files.Identity)" -output="$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)\%(SRC_GEN_XML_Files.Filename).$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_TYPE)" -lang=$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_TYPE)'/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CleanCpp" BeforeTargets="Clean" Condition="'$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_TYPE)'=='cpp'">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Removing SrcGen generated '$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)\%(SRC_GEN_XML_Files.Filename).{cpp,h}"/>
    <Delete Files='$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)\%(SRC_GEN_XML_Files.Filename).cpp'/>
    <Delete Files='$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)\%(SRC_GEN_XML_Files.Filename).h'/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CleanCs" BeforeTargets="Clean" Condition="'$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_TYPE)'=='cs'">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Removing SrcGen generated '$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)\%(SRC_GEN_XML_Files.Filename).cs"/>
    <Delete Files='$(SRC_GEN_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)\%(SRC_GEN_XML_Files.Filename).cs'/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```